# How is XHR a viable alternative to asynchronous module definition?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, requirejs, amd

I'm learning about the case for asynchronous module definition (AMD) from [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/why.html) but am not quite clear about the below:

> It is tempting to use XMLHttpRequest (XHR) to load the scripts. If XHR
>   is used, then we can massage the text above -- we can do a regexp to
>   find require() calls, make sure we load those scripts, then use eval()
>   or script elements that have their body text set to the text of the
>   script loaded via XHR.

XHR is using ajax or something to make a call to grab a resource from the database, correct? What does the eval() or script elements have to do with this? An example would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part of RequireJS' documentation is explaining why using XHR rather than doing what RequireJS does is problematic.

> XHR is using ajax or something to make a call to grab a resource from the database, correct?

XHR is what allows you to make an Ajax call. jQuery's `$.ajax` for instance creates an XHR instance for you and uses it to perform the query. How the server responds depends on how the server is designed. Most of the servers I've developed won't use a database to answer a request made to a URL that corresponds to a JavaScript file. The file is just read from the file system and sent back to the client.

> What does the eval() or script elements have to do with this?

Once the request is over, what you have is a string that contains JavaScript. You've *fetched* the code of your module but presumably you *also* want to execute it. `eval` is one way to do it but it has the disadvantages mentioned in the documentation. Another way to do it would be to create a `script` element whose body is the code you've fetched, and then insert this script in the DOM but this also has issues, as explained in the documentation you refer to.